# What is inside Erlang's digraph?

Tags: erlang, shortest-path, directed-graph

*Disclaimer: The author is a newbie in Erlang.*

I would like to implement some kind of shortest-path algorithm in Erlang.

There is a standard implementation of graph data structure in Erlang: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/digraph.html

However, I have not found any information on the actual data structure it uses.

Mostly I would like to know:

- what is the worst case performance of getting all 'neighbours' for a vertex action?
- what is the worst case performance of fetching a vertex from the graph?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A digraph uses 3 ets tables (vertices, edges and neighbour vertices).

So both of that operations are O(1).

Take a look at OTP code, it's clean and in most cases idiomatic Erlang. stdlib's gen.erl + gen_server.erl, proc_lib.erl and sys.erl are must read :)

Comment: Thank you very much! P.S. I thought the best way to learn Erlang was to read the books like "Erlang/OTP in action" etc., but it seems like I should try to read some source code as well. Should a newbie read the source code from the very beginning of the learning process? What do you think?

Comment: After becoming comfortable with functional sequential erlang - yes, definitely. So gen + gen_server will be (relatively) easy reading.